# Syntax error with || operator (PHP)

Tags: php, syntax, operators

I'm trying the `||` operator. What's wrong with the syntax of the following code?

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6')) || if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 7')) || if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 8'))
{
    echo 'something';
}
?>
```

However, the following code works fine:

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 6')) {
    echo 'something';
}
?>
```

So apparently there's something wrong with the `||` part.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not repeat the `if`.

Use it like this:

```
if(foo || bar || ...)
```

i.e.

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'MSIE 6') ||
   strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'MSIE 7') ||
   strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'MSIE 8')) {

}
```

An even nicer version would be this:

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE [6-8]/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Shall we make a bet on how many versions we can think of? :D

Comment: Thanks! :)
I accepted this answer because you explained the problem and even proposed a better version. ;)